# Split data with cut and apply a function on sub-frames

Tags: r

For the following data set:

```
> head(tmp_frame)
  t_avg_sim event
1 0.6635475     0
2 0.1500000     0
3 0.1500000     0
4 0.0000000     1
5 0.2817217     0
6 0.3854208     1
```

I'm splitting the data for 20~ subsets by `"t_avg_sim"` which are in: `seq(0, 1, by = 0.05)`

With:

```
splitted_frames <- split(tmp_frame,
                         cut(tmp_frame$t_avg_sim, seq(0, 1, by = 0.05),
                             include.lowest = TRUE))
```

Once I have all the frames I can run on each sub frame with a `for` loop and calculate the mean of the event variable. for example,

```
mean(splitted_frames$'[0,0.05]'$event)
```

Is there a way to calculate all the averages of the event variable of the sub-frames without an explicit `for` loop.

Comment: You can use the `cut` wihtin `group_by` and then `summarise` i.e. `tmp_frame %>% group_by(grp = cut(t_avg_sim, seq(0, 1, by = 0.05), include.lowest = TRUE)) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(event))`

Comment: Splendid. Can you write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of splitting into a `list` of datasets, this can be accomplished more easily with group by operation either with `aggregate` from `base R` or with `data.table` `by` method or using `dplyr` `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
tmp_frame %>%
   group_by(grp = cut(t_avg_sim, seq(0, 1, by = 0.05), include.lowest = TRUE)) %>% 
   summarise(Mean = mean(event))
```